# Find out if an item exists in a ListBox

Tags: vba, listbox

I want to find out if an item exist in the "MainList" or not to stop adding duplicate values.

```
Dim MainList As OLEObject
Set MainList = WS.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Left:=MainListCell.Left, Top:=MainListCell.Top, Width:=200, Height:=400)
```

```
If Not MainList.Object.Items.Contains(Temp(j)) Then
  MainList.Object.AddItem (Temp(j))
End If
```

but I received the error

> "Object does not support this property or method"

in the  "if" statement. How could I solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing...

```
If Not MainList.Object.Items.Contains(Temp(j)) Then
  MainList.Object.AddItem (Temp(j))
End If
```

with

```
Dim i As Long
Dim found As Boolean

found = False
With MainList.Object
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .List(i, 0) = Temp(j) Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Not found Then
        .AddItem Temp(j)
    Else
        found = False
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But adding a for loop would slow down the process.
I added a dictionary and used the method ".exists" of the dictionary to find out if an item exists in the MainList or not. Therefore, MainList and MainDict are similar but MainDict has a predefined method to find an item without slowing down the process.